# YOUTUBE DATA API: Like comment of another uer

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using PHP with google api client libraries. I have gotten a list of comment. I want to like/dislike, hide or reply comment. Please, help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YouTube api does not give you the ability to like comments. You can [update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/update) the text on your own comment and mark a comment as [spam](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/markAsSpam) but thats it.

You may want to submit this as a [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803)

Comment: Thanks! But it like that I owned channel, I call request to get all comment of video, and I have to do what to like/dislike or hide or reply any comment. That's thing I wish...

Comment: @JulianPham i understand thats what you wish.  But that is not possible.  The api does not have that feature.  As developers we are limited by what google will allow us to do not by what we would like to do.